# iPad safari and autocorrect?

Tags: ipad, autocorrect

I have configured my iPad to not do automatic autocorrect, seeing as I use the keyboard for my iPad Pro and prefer to type what I sant instead of my iPad continously secondguessing me.

However, in Safari, while typing, such as this question here, it still tries to autocorrect my typing. Is there a separate setting somewhere? I want to disable this also in Safari.

I have configured my iPad to have a Norwegian keyboard, so it continously tries to find the appropriat norwegian word which is kinda annoying.

Comment: Looks like you could use the iPad's autocorrect ability...

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear, I want to disable this also in Safari.

Comment: are you talking about proper autocorrect where it will replace the word for you? or the suggestions right above your keyboard (aka QuickType I believe)

Comment: Those boxes are not visible when I configure my iPad to use a norwegian keyboard, I am talking about the iPad immediately replacing a word after I type it. For instance, I can type "However" and as soon as I type a space the word "Hodeverk" is there instead (headache in norwegian).